# Storing image's as blob in mysql database with flutter

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart, blob

Is it good to store blob images in mysql database and fetch them in the flutter app using php or should I store them in a separate folder with their links in database? For a database with above 100K images what would be a better solution. Storing image paths would be difficult while backup i think. Can someone suggest what to do. It will be very helpful. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to store the images in a folder and just save their path's in the database. So basically convert the images to base64 and send it to your webserver in a regular POST method. then in your PHP code decode the base64 to a file and save the image wherever you want, just remember to keep track of the image new path so can fetch it later. fetching, by the way, works the same. good luck :)